# if executes despite the condition is false

Tags: javascript

*Edit: mistery solved! I had put a semicolon after the if(). Thanks Paul!*

I just have arrived to this curious situation (the snippet can be run at http://jsfiddle.net/nUs7h/ ):

```
function check_if_tag_used()
{
   var found = false;   
   return found;   
}

var used = check_if_tag_used();
console.debug(used);

if (used);
{
   alert("This should not appear!"); // why this runs?   
}
```

Why the alert() is displayed despite that the value of the variable *used* if false? Notice that console.debug() reports it as *false* indeed.

Answer (score 9):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `if`.

```
if (used);
```

Remove it.

FYI, this is why I always use the same-line brace style

```
if (used) {
   alert("This should not appear!");
}
```

It's much harder for this to happen.

Comment: **+1** good 'excuse' (that I've never heard of before) to prefer the same-line brace style (besides the obvious `return` reason (= uniformity) and the *less wasted vertical space* reason). I'm adding this example to my list.

Comment: @GitaarLAB, I'm not sure what the "return" reason is, but I have found this 'excuse' to be by far the the most objective and indisputable  argument against the unsightly space wasters.

Comment: Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion feature would result in: `return;` newline `{ /* your intended return code-block */ }` in newline-brace style, thus returning `undefined` instead of the result of your intended code-block.. Given this requirement (or gotcha) and a preferably consistent coding-style, this leads to 'same-line brace style' to be the preferable style in javascript.